# How can we best promote our work to this site's users?

Tags: discussion, users, advertising

Worldbuilding SE is a place where the users ask questions about their world building... obviously.  However, I've noticed that while asking my questions, I sometimes get comments to the effect that other users would like to see the end results.

[We have a blog](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2590/we-have-a-blog) that isn't being used much at present where users can post examples of their work.

However, I'm asking about shameless self-promotion.  Let's say that a WB SE user has asked their questions, received their answers, and produced their work based on the answers they've received.  Now they have an end result in which WB SE users may be interested, and may have *said* that they're interested.  What is the best way for such a user to promote their work?

Obviously WB SE isn't the place to do that... but is WB SE Meta an appropriate place, or is there a better place for WB SE users to promote their work that they have made with our help?

Comment: We have been talking about doing this for too long, for quite literally years people have been like “we should make a showcase post” I think we should either do that, or not do it, but stop just talking about doing it

Comment: Eh, well I’ll see you in a few months/years when this comes up again

Answer (score 6):

I think we could create a meta question here, where each answer is the information on the work. Sort of another Sandbox, but this time a Showcase box.

Comment: This has been talked about occasionally for the life of the site. [This post](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2533/how-should-we-implement-share-a-glimpse-into-your-world-week/2559#2559) last updated in 2016 seems the most comprehensive collection so far. Having a single showcase seems like a cleaner method to publicize people's work, than having a tag and individual posts per creation.

Comment: Since the post in question was (technically) about an event, I'd suggest a dedicated Wordlbuilding Showcase that is complete in and of itself.

Answer (score 5):

Creating a dedicated showcase like L.Dutch suggests is a great idea. It provides clear structure, and community support to sharing our creations. Keeping it centralized means that everyone's work will be equally discoverable. Similar to the sandbox that will also make it easier to inform people about any policy or usage guidelines.

Before creating The Showcase we should probably figure out how exactly we want it to be used. Starting with some clarity of vision should help provide a consistent experience, both for people sharing their creations, and people wanting to discover what the brilliant minds of this site have produced.

Additionally we should also encourage people to share their work on [The Factory Floor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor) and in their profiles.

The factory floor is great for works in progress. Chat provides a far less structured environment, while still granting access to the creative minds of Worldbuilding's community. This is especially useful if someone is looking for discussion, or help with brainstorming, story, characters, or any other task that isn't suitable for the main site. I don't think a showcase will be the best place to seek feedback while iterating on a work. Something more ephemeral and immediate, like chat, should help keep those creative juices flowing.

Including links to work you are proud of in your profile is less discoverable than the showcase. However it will always be directly associated with everything you do on this site. If someone finds a particularly inspired question, or inciteful answer, the author's profile is just one click away.

Creating a showcase in conjunction with encouraging the use of profiles and, and chat seems like the best way to give people recognition for their hard work. We should try to be deliberate with how we structure the showcase. If this post is well received I'll create a separate question to seek community input on how exactly we want a showcase to work.

Comment: Some time has passed since then with a well received question/answer. Do you still feel in the mood to start the showcase topic creation process, or should someone else do it in your stead?

Answer (score 1):

#### Not SE's Job ... *but*

As much as I would love to see other WB users' work, and perhaps even connect with some of you outside of SE, I really don't think SE is set up or designed to "promote our own work". I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure SE is designed as a Q&A forum, and I can't see how "Here's a link to my own fictional world" is an answer to a legitimate and non-closable query in either Main or Meta.

That said, I'm all for doing this! Just wanted to point out what I think is yet another inconsistency of WB vs SE.

We do have Universe Factory, and I think that really could be better advertised as a way of allowing users and potential users to see their respondents in action outside of the WB.SE arena.

We also have a [Worldbuilding Resources Meta Query](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/143606/a-list-of-worldbuilding-resources), and I think that we could easily add another section, maybe down at the bottom, for querents and respondents to link to "relatively substantial" examples of their creative work. I think we could explain a/o defend any accusations of blatant and shameless self promotion as links to "resources" that are designed to "inspire fellow WB users and demonstrate some of the processes and principles that we adhere to".

Comment: "which actual works have been created by using information gathered on Worlbuilding.SE?" sounds to me like a perfectly valid Meta question.

Comment: Given the other answers, a "What have you created using WB SE?" question in Meta would probably work, with each user submitting answers containing links to their own work.

Comment: @L.Dutch You mean... This kind of [question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9670/80336) :p?

Comment: @Elemtilas Let me give an "official" argument for a question on meta. From the help-center, meta is "[a place for improving our community and website, together.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)". In order to improve the website, knowing if works have been made and which kinds acts like a complement to analytic data : "Consumer" targets, site efficiency... Plus, sharing (not selling!) is caring, so it also improves the community bonds, and so the community overall.

Comment: @Tortliena --- That's the one I'm thinking of! And the answer to *that* query would certainly be an "improvement to the community" in a way that me or L. Dutch or you or JBH posting links to our own works would not be.

Comment: @Elemtilas It really depends, actually. If I am just posting to sell my work, yes, it doesn't bring anything and worse, it could bring a "People are just here to sell their books" mood. However, if given context to this site like "what question helped me the most in my work?" or "What did I learn when I asked on this website (beyond the question's answers)?", it can really help see what worked and what needs to be thought again. Telling this through your work is a really good start and it'll motivate volunteers when they see something at the end.

Answer (score 0):

#### Blatant Self Promotion: Show Don't Tell

One way for those of us who answer questions to do this is to simply give an answer that makes use of our own worldbuilding, and better still, could actually be an example of an in-world artifact.

With this Meta question in mind, I answered a recent Main question with a piece of pure worldbuilding.

The question about a [geocentric world](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/237643/37029). As an answer, it was fairly well received, and I think could serve as a model for others to do likewise. I don't think this could work for every situation, but it is one way of offering a creative answer that both answers the question and showcases some aspect of worldbuilding.

I've done this before, and I'd be curious to know what others think about this.